# trocar o texto quando soltar o botão

Tags: python, python-kivy, kivy

é pra clicar no botão e quando soltar ele trocar o texto o framework que eu uso é o kivy do python já troquei a indentação e nada

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        button = Button(text ="Botão 1")
        label = Label(text="Texto 1",font_size=30,on_release=self.incrementar)
        box.add_widget(button)
        box.add_widget(label)
        return box

    def incrementar(self,button):
        button.text = 'Soltei'




Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para trocar o texto do label podes definir o label como membro da classe para poderes chamar na outra função. E tens que chamar o evento on_release no botão em vez do label.

```
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        self.label = Label(text="Texto 1",font_size=30)
        button = Button(text ="Botão 1", on_release=self.incrementar)
        box.add_widget(button)
        box.add_widget(self.label)
        return box
```